# How to get clock from a date

Tags: java, android, date

I have `Date` like this `Sun May 20 09:18:44 GMT+04:30 2018` how i can get clock from this `Date`,
i want result like this `09:18 am`

```
Log.v(TAG,"date "+ date.toString());// output is Sun May 20 09:18:44 GMT+04:30 2018
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
String time=sdf.format(date);//NullPointerException
```

Comment: Post the code where you are initializing the date variable.

Comment: How is `date` initialized?

Comment: add `Date date=new Date();`

Comment: `date` is `null`. And use `new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a")`.

Comment: i'm sure date is not null

Comment: Don't be sure on your own. Provide the Exception report in question.

Comment: I cannot reproduce either. `date` is obviously non-null in the `Log.v` line, and then I cannot get any `NullPointerException`. For help with this one please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Thanks to everyone ,that was my fault,and yes date is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is working you just have to initialize Date class's object
          **Date date = new Date();**

```
    Date date = new Date();
    Log.v(TAG,"date "+ date.toString());
    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
    String time=sdf.format(date);
    Log.v(TAG,"date "+ time);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code..

```
        SimpleDateFormat sdf3 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf4 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);

    Date d1 = null;
    try{
        d1 = sdf3.parse("Sun May 20 09:18:44 GMT+04:30 2018");
        String date=sdf4.format(d1);
        System.out.println("time..." + date);

    }catch (Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }


    System.out.println("check..." + d1);
```